# Javaquery onchange if min-max value

Tags: jquery, html

I need code that changes input value if its above max or belove min number.
For example min is 1 and max 10. If input is set to 15 then it changes to 10 and if its set to 0 then it changes to 1. And it should work without reloading page.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you are using HTML5, `<input type="number" min="1" max="10"/>` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `min` and `max` attributes of the `number`-typed `input` element:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" placeholder="Enter a number between 1 and 10" />
```

The form will prevent the user from entering values outside of the range, without any coding.

If you want your input to support decimals, add the `step="any"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use as

Here's a simple function that does what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseInt(value) < 0 || isNaN(value)) 
        return 1; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > 10) 
        return 10; 
    else return value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 10)"/>
```

If the input is not numeric it replaces is with  1